# CSS for circumventing ananoymous DIV

Tags: css

I am using a CMS which when building a form wraps all it's contents with what it calls an "anonymous div" to comply with XHTML, unfortunately the theme was designed without this insight and there fore the submit button CSS is:

```
.contact form div.control input[type=submit]
```

This works if the markup is:

```
<section class="contact">
  <form>
    <div class="control">
      <input type="submit" />
```

However because this additional DIV added by CMS:

```
<section class="contact">
  <form>
    <div>
      <div class="control">
        <input type="submit" />
```

How can I write the CSS a bit more adaptive so extra markup doesn't affect it so much, but without styling the individual element via ID or class???

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should still select the input, the div won't affect that. If the div is causing layout problems, you might need to make it an inline element like this:

`section > form > div { display: inline }`

Comment: It's not a layout it's the background and rounded corners...when I drop that anonymous DIV it works as expected :s

Comment: Maybe you should post a screenshot. I can't imagine what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add:

`.contact form div div.control input[type=submit]`

or

`.contact form div .control input[type=submit]`.

Either should work fine.